# Generate Fragment out of a ExpandableListActivity?

Tags: android

I have a `ExpandableListActivity` and now want to extend my app. This is why I need make a `ExpandableListActivity` to a `Fragment`. I need to show a additional Fragment in the Activity, this is the reason.

Is this even possible? How to do it?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more as to what the `Fragment` should provide and how it would extend the functionality provided by the `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use and show the `ExpandableListView` in `Fragment` also. Just you have to decide the layout design of it. You can load the fragment which contains the `ExpandableListView` and other layout below it where you can load another `Fragment`.